# Should I stick with the ReportViewer control or buy a third party tool?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

we need reports in our web application and there is the free ReportViewer Control from microsoft (normally used, to display reports from the reporting services). I like the fact, that the Report Format (.RDL-Format) from the ReportViewer is a documented XML-Format. But the functionality is somewhat limited, when the ReportViewer is used without the ReportingServices.

Is there a good replacement, which is based or compatible with the .RDL-Format?

The first Reports are build in the application, but later, the customer should make his reports by himself.

**The Application is a ASP.NET Web-Application**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depend on your requirements. I am not clear what your requirements are.

Is your application a web application or a desktop application?

If your application is a **web application** then you can use any other reporting service. I like **[i-net Clear Reports](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystalclear/)**. There is also a free and fully functional GUI [report designer](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystal-clear/designer) that is easy to use. Your customer can create your own reports.

If you have a **desktop application** then you are limit to the language of your application.

You should also think about the platforms. The reporting services are limited to windows and a SQL Server is needed. Does all your customer have a SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I have forgotten to write, that the application is a asp.net web application